# Apex 'variable does not exist'

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components

I encountered an issue, as I want to access a property of an object I'm passing from a lwc to an apex method, like this:

```
valuesObj.ml_id = this.sfItem.id;
this.itemObj = valuesObj;
```

and then:

```
processItemEdit( {item : this.itemObj} ).then(r => {
     console.log('r', r);
});
```

This is the apex method:

```
@AuraEnabled
public static void processItemEdit(CsvItem item){
    List<CsvItem> items = new List<CsvItem>();
    String seller_id = String.valueOf(item.ml_id);
    Seller_Setting__c setting = SellerSettingDataManager.getSetting(seller_id);
    setting = BatchApexListItems.getSetting(setting.id);
    items.add(item);
    BatchApexListItems.processItemsCsv(items, setting);
}
```

For some reason, apex throws an error when I try to deploy, saying the variable 'item.ml_id' does not exist, when it is defined in the first line of code I included here. What is going on?

Comment: Can you share CsvItem apex class also?

Comment: oohh I understand the problem. If that class doesn't have that property, apex won't find it. The object I created in the component does have the property but when converted to CsvItem, it doesn' translate, right?

Comment: Yes. You have got it right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I see you have just created the object `CsvItem` on the client side.
But when the object is passed to server side, i.e. Apex, you need same properties in Apex class defined as 'CsvItem'

For eg:

```
public class CsvItem{

    public String ml_id {get ; set; }
}
```

Comment: that was the problem. Anyway, I solved it by passing the right properties directly from the lwc. thanks for the help